# Getting Date from a file on a remote FTP Server

Tags: powershell, ftp-client

To get a file, the Method looks like this:

```
$ftprequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::DownloadFile
```

So, I am trying to change the Method to be equivalent to the C# code below:

```
request.Method = System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp;
```

How can I use GetDateTimestamp  in powershell?

I have tried the following variations without any luck yet:

```
$ftprequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp.GetDateTimestamp]
$ftprequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp+GetDateTimestamp]
$ftprequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp.GetDateTimestamp]
$ftprequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods.Ftp+GetDateTimestamp]
```

bonus question:  what is the :: mean on the first code example mean?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This seems to work:

```
$ftprequest.Method = [System.Net.WebRequestMethods+Ftp]::GetDateTimestamp
```

`::` is to access shared/static members, which `GetDateTimeStamp` is.